# Windows print portrait AND landscape

Tags: windows, printing

I took pictures of the pages I needed from a textbook so that I could access them from my computer. I was taking portrait pictures of each individual page until I realized the quality was good enough to get both pages in one landscape shot, so half the pictures I have are portrait pics of one page and the other half are landscape of two pages. I'm trying to print to pdf, but Windows only gives the option to print portrait, which rotates all the landscape pictures, or vice versa.

Comment: hat PDF editor are you using?

Comment: Should be able to have acrobat print with auto portrait/landscape option on.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is what you are going to get.  You can accomplish what you want, however, it will require either A) Printing each individual page separately and using a PDF tool to combine them or B) Using a PDF tool to rotate individual pages of the complete document.  I personally use pdftk under linux and it seems they now have a windows version:  https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/ I did find this link:  http://www.pdfill.com/pdf_tools_free.html for another tool you can use.